# Calling jQuery methods on html elements that won't execute

Tags: jquery, methods, syntax

I'm wondering how common this is used by people, and if it's OK practice or not.

For example, I have

```
$('.class1').on('click', function() {
     $('.class1, .class2, .class3').hide().off();
     x = 50;
});
```

`.class1` and `.class2` both need the `.hide()` and `.off()` methods.

`.class3` only needs the `.hide()` method. `.class3` is an input field and never uses a click function in my program.

So is it OK to write it above like that?

Or should I just write it like this?

```
$('.class1').on('click', function() {
     $('.class1, .class2').hide().off();
     $('.class3').hide();
     x = someVar / 50;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the first method is just fine. jQuery is very tolerant to no-op method calls. For example, this returns an empty, but otherwise fully usable jQuery object, rather than failing loudly: `$('#some-element-id-which-does-not-exist')`.

However, [the no-arg version of `.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/#off) is a little picky:

> Calling `.off()` with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names. **When multiple filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the event handler to be removed.**

So, whether or not it'll work depends on how you originally called `.on()`.